# How to Round Down MySQL Date with Moment.JS?

Tags: mysql, date, momentjs

I have this MySQL date:

```
2016-07-30T23:15:31.000Z
```

When I moment it:

```
var a = moment('2016-07-30T23:15:31.000Z').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(a);
```

I got this
`31-07-2016`

How can I get it to `30-07-2016`?

Comment: sorry I don't understand, what would you like to figure out?

Comment: Try as `moment.utc('2016-07-30T23:15:31.000Z').format('DD-MM-YYYY')`